# How to populate firebase collection to TabBar tabs children

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How to populate firebase collection data into my TabBar?

I already create a **TabBar** with dummy data and running well in my app. But I confused how to use my collection data from firebase to replace my dummy data.

Listview Tab

```
body: ListView(
  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
  children: <Widget>[
    SizedBox(height: 15.0),
    TabBar(
      controller: _tabController,
      indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
      labelColor: PrimaryColor,
      isScrollable: true,
      labelPadding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 45.0),
      unselectedLabelColor: lightGray,
      tabs: [
        BuildTab(title: "Cookies"),
        BuildTab(title: "Noodle"),
        BuildTab(title: "Ice Cream"),
        BuildTab(title: "Burger"),
        BuildTab(title: "Pizza"),
      ],
    ),
    Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: [
          CategoryItem(),
          CategoryItem(),
          CategoryItem(),
          CategoryItem(),
          CategoryItem(),
        ],
      ),
    )
  ],
),
```

I already connect with my firestore

```
class _CategoryPageState extends State<CategoryPage>
  with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
TabController _tabController;

StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot> subscription;
List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot;

CollectionReference collectionReference =
    Firestore.instance.collection("categories");

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _tabController = TabController(
    length: 5,
    vsync: this,
  );
  subscription = collectionReference.snapshots().listen((datasnapshot) {
    setState(() {
      snapshot = datasnapshot.documents;
    });
  });
}
```

My collection name is **categories**
[image]

How to use `snapshot[index]` ?

I want to get collection data **drinks** and **foo**d to become TabBar

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving a list of collections is not possible with the mobile/web client libraries
source:https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document

Comment: That's mean I should change my data structure on firestore?

Comment: @BerthoJoris yes or you get these collection names using cloud functions(an api call integration required in the app )and you will be missing the subscription model but you can use the same data structure

Comment: How about merge sub collection (it's mean drink and food) into documents? And result is `categories` collection => documents. I edit document field and add drink and food to each document. Final result is I have many documents in categories collection. Do you get my idea?

Comment: That will work and just get the document.id and use that for your tab name

Comment: @BerthoJoris this is how I managed when I worked for a restaurant app which has the same use case of yours but I was just using these categories in separate collections and each food item has the category id as a field

Comment: Yes... I start for creating restaurant app using flutter (newbie) and start with firebase. Wish you want help me for creating schema :) I create like this https://i.ibb.co/d5j3hc2/ignored.png how about it?

Comment: Or I must separated tab menu in `each` document ?

Comment: Would not be able to comment on the above until i completely understand the structure of other items and how u r using these categories

Comment: Maybe you can read my idea here https://pastebin.com/i9srMbc3 Need your advice

Comment: @BerthoJoris your thought will work for now as you mentioned in here. https://i.ibb.co/d5j3hc2/ignored.png but if you have any relation with menus later its hard to maintain. so better you separate the menu's and just maintain the id's in the documents